# Why not both ORM and SQL?

Tags: sql, orm

In the seemingly eternal struggle between ORM and SQL-programming, there comes a question:
Why not use both? Using ORM for most of the programming, and program my own SQL-queries for the more complex JOIN-queries and other complex queries the chosen ORM cannot do. Are there any good reasons not to?

Comment: that seems perfectly fine, that is what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ORM solutions support native SQL - e.g. [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).

The reason NOT to combine the two is one of consistency - if you have to understand two ways of retrieving data from the database and converting them to objects in your application, you have twice as much to remember, twice as many opportunities for bugs, and twice as much testing to do (for the "connect to database and retrieve data" code).

What happens in practice is that developers who are not comfortable with ORM will tend to use native SQL, and developers who like the ORM tool will do nearly everything using the ORM layer - this will make your codebase hard to maintain and extend.

If you're going to do this, I'd at least enforce the "do SQL through the ORM tool, not directly through JDBC (or whatever)" rule - that gives you at least some consistency, and you can re-use a lot of the object mapping functionality.

Ideally, though, pick a solution and stick with it - hedging your bets is rarely free.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the cases ORM generated SQL are non-optimized.

It is suggested where performance matters that, Use ORM for binding only and use user-defined SQL for all the queries.

Comment: I read somewhere that combining both was not recommended by the producers of ORM-tools, without any reasons mentioned. However, when I google it, I find almost nothing on that.